# Is there a way to load up images before they are in view in React?

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm very new to react and so far the most confusing/frustrating part has been trying to deal with image URLs expiring right after the API call. I'm building a platform with multiple pages, and each page contains many different images (which are fetched from a server). But, the URLs for the images expires after 10 seconds, so if I don't switch to the pages displaying the images within 10 seconds (so they can load), they will never show.

I'm just wondering what the best way to do this is? I could make an API call every time I need to load up the images ie every time I switch components/pages. But this actually turns out to be quite slow as it takes about 4 seconds to retrieve all of the information.

Here is when I reach one of the pages [in time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d2mR.png) Vs. when I reach it [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt2i0.png) 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentDidMount()` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook for HTTP request. This article may useful for you [lifecycle react methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thats how I'm fetching the data. As you can see I'm not having trouble getting the data, its just the image URLs that expire.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the images, you can store the images in localStorage and fetch it from there to display on the UI. In this way, you will always have access to the images and once the page is reloaded use componentWillUnmount and remove those images from localStorage. Hope this helps.